# Print breadcrumbs recursive from one mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, breadcrumbs

I have a multidimensional menu saved in MySQL. Table look like:

```
id name parent_id
```

The table is huge. I don't want to run hundreds of mysql_query() so I started with this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
$arrs = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $arrs[] = $row;
}

function build_tree($arrs, $parent_id=0, $level=0) {
    foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
        if ($arr['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
            echo str_repeat("-", $level)." ".$arr['name']."<br />";
            build_tree($arrs, $arr['id'], $level+1);
        }
    }
}

build_tree($arrs);
```

This works just fine, but how do I modify this to **print all parent_ids** for each post? Almost like breadcrumbs.

Comment: Is this a legacy application? You should not be using `mysql_query` in new applications.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Yes, this is an update for an old project. I usually use codeigniter framework for new projects, but thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing in only one parent_id, you can pass in an array of parent_ids. You can append the current parent_id into this array before the recursive call, and remove it after the recursive call.